# How to View KdPrint Messages WDK 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windbg, wdk

I just started to learn driver development using VS2012 + WDK8. I have some KdPrint statements in DriverEntry to print out some messages. Where can I get these messages?

Comment: Aren't they sent to the kernel debugger? You could fire up DebugView and see them ... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: Thank you Roger. It works. Also, do you know if I can view the messages within VS2012?

Comment: I don't think so but I don't have WDK8 to check, sorry.